# Sqlite Update query with SqliteModernCpp

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, c++11

I am using the SqliteModernCpp library. I have a data access object pattern, including the following function:

```
void movie_data_access_object::update_movie(movie to_update)
{
    // connect to the database
    sqlite::database db(this->connection_string);

    // execute the query
    std::string query = "UPDATE movies SET title = " + to_update.get_title() + " WHERE rowid = " + std::to_string(to_update.get_id());
    db << query;
}
```

Essentially, I want to update the record in the database whose `rowid` (the PK) has the value that the object `to_update` has in its parameter (which is returned by `get_id()`).

This code yields an SQL logic error. What is the cause of this?

Comment: Most likely, `to_update.get_title()` returns a string that's not quoted as a string literal, so the query becomes nonsense. Also, you are inviting [SQL injection](https://bobby-tables.com/). Use a parameterized query instead; the [README](https://github.com/SqliteModernCpp/sqlite_modern_cpp/blob/master/README.md) for the library shows how.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out single quotes (') within the query string being created were missing. The line should be:

```
std::string query = "UPDATE movies SET title = '" + to_update.get_title() + "' WHERE rowid = " + std::to_string(to_update.get_id());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no UPDATE example in the official docs on github, This is how UPDATE queries should be implemented with prepared statements and binding

```
#define MODERN_SQLITE_STD_OPTIONAL_SUPPORT
#include "sqlite_modern_cpp.h"

struct Book {
    int id;
    string title;
    string details;

    Book(int id_, string title_, string details_):
        id(std::move(id_)),
        title(std::move(title_)),
        details(std::move(details_)) {}
}

int main() {
    Book book = Book(0, "foo", "bar")

    sqlite::database db("stackoverflow.db");

    // Assuming there is a record in table `book` that we want to `update`
    db <<
    " UPDATE book SET "
    "   title   = ?, "
    "   details = ?  "
    " WHERE id = ?; "
    << book.title
    << book.details
    << book.id;

    return 0;
}
```